# Mongodb nested document where clause returns many subdocuments

Tags: php, mongodb, nested-documents

I have a mongodb document that looks similar to this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "This is the title",
"body" : "This is the body",
"comments": [
    {
        "email_address": "mirko.benedetti@somemail.com",
        "name": "Mirko",
        "surname": "Benedetti",
        "language": "it",
        "text": "This is a message",
        "published": "Y",
        "on": "2014-03-22 15:04:04"
    },
    {
        "email_address": "marc.surname@somemail.com",
        "name": "Marc",
        "surname": "Surname",
        "language": "it",
        "text": "Another Message",
        "published": "N",
        "on": "2014-03-23 15:04:05"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I have a query like this:

```
$this->db->collection->find(array('id' => $id, 'language' => $lang, 'comments.published' => 'Y'),
                        array('comments.name' => 1, 'comments.surname' => 1, 'comments.text' => 1, 'comments.on' => 1, '_id' => 0));
```

My problem is that running that query, mongodb returns both comments, which I don't want, I want only the message with "published": "Y".

I tried for example to run 'comments.published' => 'something' and none comment is selected, which is correct, but if at least one of the comments has
the flag "published" set to 'Y', both comments are showed.

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: I tried to add one more comment with "published" set to "N", and it gives me 3 records, with var_dump, the resulting array is of 3 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [$elemMatch documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)

```
db.schools.find( { zipcode: "63109" },
                 { students: { $elemMatch: { school: 102 } } } )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful while using the elemMatch operator. First thing it has two variants. [$elemMatch(projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) & [$elemMatch(query)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

The elemMatch(projection) variant appears to working because the filter criteria you have only matches to one value in comments array.

The below query will work fine.

```
find({'_id' : ObjectId("582f2abf9b549b5a765ab380"), comments: { $elemMatch: { language: "it", published : "Y" }}})
```

Now consider when you have more than 1 matching values (two values with 'Y' published status) in comments arrays, then the above query will not work and will only return the first matching value.

In this scenario, you will need to use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), which will filter the comments array based on the filter crtieria passed.

```
aggregate([{
    $match: {
        '_id': ObjectId("582f2abf9b549b5a765ab380")
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "comments": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$comments",
                "as": "result",
                "cond": {
                    $and: [{
                        $eq: ["$$result.language", "it"]
                    }, {
                        $eq: ["$$result.published", "Y"]
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "comments": {
            name: 1,
            surname: 1,
            text: 1,
            on: 1
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: My problem is also that I have to select "comments" inside a certain document ("blog_post") but I have also to select the **right document** (blog_post) and that is not very intuitive from the documentation, with aggregate.

Comment: you will just need to add match stage, considering the query criteria same as what we use in find method Updated answer. Hope thats what you meant from your previous comment.

Comment: What if I want to pick only certain elements of "comments"?

Comment: you will just need to add another project to include certain fields from nested array. Updated answer.

Comment: Finally I had to sort the nested documents "comments", but the only way to make it work was to use $unwind before, like this: `{'$unwind' : '$comments'},
{'$sort': {'comments.on' => -1}}` is it correct?

Comment: Yes unwind is required if you needed to sort the nested array document.